# c# Escape Seq \n not working

Tags: c#, escaping

I am trying to insert a new line like this in a WinForm app:VS2015 .net 4.5

```
  class Program
{
    private static List<ZONE> zones;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("line1" + Environment.NewLine);
        sb.Append("line2");

    }

}
```

sb.ToString does not contain a line break between "line1" and "line2"
I do not know why.

Comment: Try Environment.NewLine

Comment: I am developing a WinForm app

Comment: Code you've provided will construct string with multiple `\n` characters. As such - voting to close as "no repro". Most likely problem is not related to how you construct string, but rather how you show it.

Comment: Whats wrong with using `sb.AppendLine()` instead of `.Append()`. Does it for you.

Comment: BTW, if you debug your code and try sb.ToString() in the console, you are not going to see new lines. To check if it is ok, add a label to your form and assign to its Text property your sb.ToString(). That way you'll see the new lines

Comment: @Pikoh - Even in debug it will show the breaks.

Comment: @Gabe I've just tried it in VS2008. If you inspect the value using the "magnifier", it shows the breaks, but if you type sb.ToString() in the Immediate Window(i think that is how it's called,my vs is in spanish), it won't show them

Comment: @Pikoh - sorry didn't take localization into account.

Comment: @Gabe I don't think it's a localization problem. The thing is I think the OP expects to see 2 lines when trying to inspect the sb value, and he instead is seeing something like "line1/r/nline2",what is ok but he thinks it isn't.. :)

Comment: @Pikoh makes sense, hood catch :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

  sb.Append("line1");
  sb.AppendLine();
  sb.Append("line2");

  String result = sb.ToString();
```

Or even better this:

```
  String result = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, "line1", "line2");
```

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of `\n` depends on the platform you are using. If you on windows, it is `\r\n` actually.

But as a better, use [`Environment.NewLine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline) property instead.

Comment: @PaulStanley What do you mean by _does not work_ exactly? You get error or exception? Unexpected result? How do you show your string by the way? Can you please be more specific about _what_ and _how_ is not working?

Comment: @PaulStanley see my comment to your question. I think the problem is you are trying yo inspect the StringBuilder value in debug mode, instead of showing it in a control.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`StringBuilder.AppendLine()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebk18257(v=vs.110).aspx) it automatically appends the current `Environment.NewLine` value.

```
 class Program
 {
    private static List<ZONE> zones;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendLine("line1");
        sb.AppendLine("line2");
        Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());

    }
}
```

Breakpoint on `sb.ToString()` has [THIS](https://i.gyazo.com/2d2f3b8a68dbdd84432d24cb0dab5390.png) within it, as you can see the breaks are there.

So it will output what you expect, or at least should. This doesn't take localization issues into account.